# Launch one more chromium non-headless mode puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

My program launches chromium in headless mode. Can i launch one more chromium in this program, but in non-headless mode?

Comment: Yes with `{ headless : false }`, it's in [the doc](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer).

Comment: yes, I know it. but my problem is different. the whole script works in headless mode, and at one point I need to open another chromium without closing the previous one, but only in non-headless mode

Comment: And did you try opening another Puppeteer instance in headful mode? :)

Comment: Just in the middle of the code, despite the fact that at first there is `const browser = await puppeteer.launch ({headless: true,})` in the middle of the code write `const browservis = await puppeteer.launch ({headless: false,})`?

Comment: Well yes, did you try that?

Comment: Lol, it works, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just launch another browser instance with `const browser2 = await puppeteer.launch ({headless: false})`.